# OPC Foundation Tree structure

Tags: treeview, opc

I've been searching the web, but I can't figure out how to get a tree view of the items on an OPC server. I used the following code:

```
 using Opc.Da;
 using Server=Opc.Da.Server;
 using Factory=OpcCom.Factory;

 string urlstring = string.Format("opcda://{0}/{1}/{{{2}}}", _hostName, _serverName, serverid);
 Server s = new Server(new Factory(), new URL(urlstring));
 ItemIdentifier itemId = null;
 BrowsePosition position;
 BrowseFilters filters = new BrowseFilters() {BrowseFilter = browseFilter.item};
 BrowseElement[] elements = s.Browse(itemId, filters, out position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not state what precisely does not work. However, the main problems is probably in the fact that you are using BrowseFilter = browseFilter.item. The nodes in the tree are either leaves (sometimes called items), or branches. Your code only asks for the leafs, under the root of the tree. There may be no items under the root whatsoever, and you need to obtain the branches as well, and then dwelve deeper into the branches, recursively.

Start by changing your code to use BrowseFilter = browseFilter.all. This should give you all nodes under the root. Then, call the Browse recursively for the branches (just branches, not items) you receive, using the item ID of each branch as the starting point for the new browse.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example of how to search the next leaf after I searched root?